# investigate conditional and absolute convergence of improper integral

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, improper-integrals, uniform-convergence, absolute-convergence

Investigate the improper integral for conditional and absolute convergence at different values of the parameter α
$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-x}{x^{2}\sin(x^{\alpha })}dx$$

As I understand I should consider the cases α=0, α>0, α<0. I may use equivalence in the first two cases. But what else I can use here and how? In the latter case,I  make a replacement $t= x^{\alpha }$ but in the neighborhood of the zeros of the sine will be bad because there would be a bunch of zeroes of sine and all are not integrable
Can anyone please help me to solve it?

Comment: @Masacroso The issue is convergence or lack thereof when $\alpha<0$.

Comment: @julia You are on the right track with your thinking about the case in which $\alpha<0$.  If you enforce the substitution $x\mapsto 1/x^{1/\alpha}$, the issue of the singularities at points for which the sine function is $0$ are more visibly pronounced and it is clear that the integral diverges.